# Re-run HTTP request as part of AsyncTask

Tags: android, android-asynctask

(Updated for clarity) I might need to re-run an HTTP request in an Android AsyncTask based on the result I get back. I've pasted a simple example of an asynchronous task below. Instead of getting back an error code, I would be getting back a temporary working-id that tells me the server is processing my request. I need to check back every few seconds and send the server the working-id until it finishes and gives me my data. That's it! Sounds pretty simple but I can't seem to figure it out:

```
private class HttpGetter extends AsyncTask<URL, Void, Void> {

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(URL... urls) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
        HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet(urls[0]);

        try {
            HttpResponse response = client.execute(httpGet);
            StatusLine statusLine = response.getStatusLine();
            int statusCode = statusLine.getStatusCode();

            if (statusCode == 200) {
                HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
                InputStream content = entity.getContent();
                BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(content));
                String line;
                while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                    builder.append(line);
                }
                Log.v("Getter", "Your data: " + builder.toString()); // response
                                                                     // data
            } else {
                Log.e("Getter", "Failed to download file");
            }
        } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return null;
    }
}
```

Then using the AsyncTask:

```
HttpGetter get = new HttpGetter();
get.execute("http://www.google.es");
```

Comment: Are you saying that this jsonParser will never actually "finish" not even after getting a ticket?

Comment: Let me edit the code real quick, it's unnecessarily confusing...

Comment: @HalR - I've updated this thread with a much simpler example and explanation

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is an improved version of your `Getter` `AsyncTask` which fetches your "working id" and uses it to poll the HTTPd until something comes back.
You need to modify at least the parts marked with `TODO` comments to match your needs.

```
private class HttpGetter extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Void> {

    private String parseWorkingId(String responseData) {
        // TODO: implement me: parse json/xml/whatever
        return responseData;
    }

    private String getWorkingId(HttpClient client, String url) throws IOException {
        StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
        HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet(url);

        HttpResponse response = client.execute(httpGet);
        StatusLine statusLine = response.getStatusLine();
        int statusCode = statusLine.getStatusCode();

        if (statusCode == 200) {
            HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
            InputStream content = entity.getContent();
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(content));
            String line;
            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                // don't forget to add the stripped line ending
                builder.append(line).append("\n");
            }
            String responseData = builder.toString();
            Log.v("Getter", "Your data: " + responseData);
            return parseWorkingId(responseData);
        } else {
            Log.e("Getter", "Failed to download file");
            throw new IOException("download failed");
        }
    }

    private String getData(HttpClient client, String url, String workingId) throws IOException {
        // TODO is result data a String? maybe you want to use a Stream
        StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
        // TODO change me to something matching your needs
        HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet(url + "?workingId=" + Uri.encode(workingId));

        HttpResponse response = client.execute(httpGet);
        StatusLine statusLine = response.getStatusLine();
        int statusCode = statusLine.getStatusCode();

        if (statusCode == 200) {
            HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
            InputStream content = entity.getContent();
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(content));
            String line;
            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                // don't forget to add the stripped line ending
                builder.append(line).append("\n");
            }
            String responseData = builder.toString();
            if (responseData.length() > 0) {
                Log.v("Getter", "Your data: " + responseData);
                return responseData;
            } else {
                Log.v("Getter", "nothing here yet");
                return null;
            }
        } else {
            Log.e("Getter", "Failed to download file");
            return null;
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(String... urls) {
        String url = urls[0];
        HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
        String data = null;

        try {
            // get working id
            String workingId = getWorkingId(client, url);

            // loop for getting data
            while (true) { // TODO add timeout or some other sane break condition
                data = getData(client, url, workingId);
                if (data == null) {
                    try {
                        Thread.sleep(10 * 1000); // 10s
                    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                } else {
                    break;
                }
            }
        } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        if (data != null) {
            // TODO do something with data
            Log.v("Getter", "here is your data: " + data);
        }

        // maybe you want to return data to onPostExecute()
        return null;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, I'll check it out and get back to you

Comment: I had to make a few adjustments for my particular scenario, but it seems to work fine. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

In fact your code could work well, but there are still some places could be improved.

1. Need to terminate. After looping several times, it should be terminated.
2. Error handing. When some http exceptions are raised, whether continue to run or just break.
3. Sleep time. Double the sleep time in each iteration.

PS: there is also a bug here, maybe you just forget to include in.

```
String status = jsonObject.getString("status").toString();
```

This line should also be put inside the loop.